# Spinnaker: set stage param to piepline param if set otherwise to a pipeline expression using trigger params

Tags: spinnaker

Problem Summary:

- Set an envvar for a stage to an optional pipeline param if it is not null (for manual execution case)
- Set an envvar for a stage to a pipeline expression value using trigger params if pipeline param is null (for triggered execution from jenkins)

Details:

I have an optional pipeline param APK_URL. If it is set then I want to use it as set as an envVar APK_URL for the stage. If it is not set then I want it to use a url made using trigger parameters using a pipeline expression. I tried the following:

```
{
  ...
  "parameterConfig": [
    {
      "description": "The url  or url-key for apk to deploy to device",
      "label": "APK_URL",
      "name": "APK_URL",
      "required": false
    }
  ],
  "stages": [
    {
      ...
      "containers": [
        {
          "args": [],
          "command": [
            "./scripts/entrypoint-deploy.sh"
          ],
          "envVars": [
            {
              "name": "APK_URL",
              "value": "(${parameters[\"APK_URL\"]} != null) ? ${parameters[\"APK_URL\"]} : https://my.com/application/${trigger['buildInfo']['scm']['branch']/${trigger['buildInfo']['artifacts'][0]['displayPath']}"
            }
          ],
          ...
        }
       ]
   ...
}
```

When I run the pipeline manually (no trigger) with APK_URL param specified it gives an error:

`Failed to evaluate [value] EL1007E: Property or field 'branch' cannot be found on null`

It seems that the java ternary operator is evaluating the url made from trigger parameters even though APK_URL is not null.

Can someone tell me how I set the stage parameter to pipeline parameter for manual execution and set stage parameter to pipeline expression for triggered execution. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Spinnaker does not provide such functionality directly.

But you can do it in several different ways:

- Script Stage
- Jenskins Stage
- Run Job Stage

And implement what ever logic you need there.

Another option is to add several condition stages which will be skipped depened on your input.